# The problem with add 2nd datasource with mybatis ORM in jhipster 5.7.2 project

Tags: jhipster, mybatis

The problem with add 2nd datasource with mybatis ORM in jhipster 5.7.2 project

1、add configuration
MatchingDatabaseConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = "sample.mybatis.domain")
@MapperScan(basePackages = "sample.mybatis.dao", sqlSessionTemplateRef = "matchingSqlSessionTemplate")
public class MatchingDatabaseConfiguration {
    private String localMapper = "classpath:mappers/*.xml";

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("application.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties matchingDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("application.datasource")
    public DataSource matchingDataSource() {
        return matchingDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingTransactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager matchingTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(matchingDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingSqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory matchingSqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(matchingDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().
            getResources(localMapper));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingSqlSessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate buildSqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("matchingSqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingTransaction")
    public PlatformTransactionManager matchingTransactionManager(@Qualifier("matchingDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

2  application-dev.yml

```
application:
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
        username: root
        password:
```

3 ApplicationProperties.java
add properties field

https://github.com/jnuc093/xpdjh/blob/master/src/main/java/com/isunland/app/config/ApplicationProperties.java

4 add the mybatis sample xml files
https://github.com/jnuc093/xpdjh/tree/master/src/main/resources/mappers

5 add sample.mybatis package 
https://github.com/jnuc093/xpdjh/tree/master/src/main/java/sample/mybatis

6 add Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CityResource {

    @Autowired
    private CityDao cityDao;

    @Autowired
    private HotelDao hotelDao;

    @GetMapping("/test-mybatis/{cityId}")
    public Hotel run(@PathVariable int cityId) {
        return hotelDao.selectByCityId(cityId);
    }
}
```

7  The official mybatis sample is here

https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml

When i access http://localhost:9000/api/test-mybatis/123

```
Response Body
{
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "Could not find result map sample.mybatis.dao.CityDao.City",
  "path": "/api/test-mybatis/123",
  "message": "error.http.500"
}
```

How can i fix this problem